# Compare Id from a Comma separated value in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a column in which UserIds are stored in a comma separated form (as shown below). Now I have a problem that I need to check whether the current user is available in that list or not.

```
Id     UserId 
--  ---------------
1    10,11,12,13    
2    10,13,15,4
```

I have used split function for this but that was taking too much time because I have millions of records and having 20 other columns.

Comment: What is the point of posting a question then immediately posting an answer? Maybe if it were an interesting question, but this one isn't. It's been asked before many, many times.

Comment: I am just sharing a knowledge because I just found this and it has improved so much performance of my Stored Procedure. One more reason might someone can suggest me a better answer which will help me to improve this more.

Answer (score 3):

try it:

```
 select * from yourtable
 where UserId like '%,' + idtocheck + ',%' or
 UserId like  idtocheck + ',%' or
 UserId like '%,' + idtocheck  or
 UserId = idtocheck
```

Answer (score 1):

Another sleek solution to check these comma delimited lists is something like:

**Sample Data**

```
Declare @Table TABLE(Id INT,UserId VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
( 1  ,  '10,11,12,13'),    
( 2  ,  '10,13,15,4');
```

**Query**

```
Declare @UserIDToCheck INT = 10;   --<-- Id to check 

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT    Id
            , RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) UserID
    FROM   
        (
        SELECT   Id
                , Cast ('<X>' + Replace(UserId, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM    @Table
        ) AS t 
        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
)A
WHERE UserID = @UserIDToCheck
```

**Note**

But most importantly you need to fix your schema, if you are using any relational database to store your data, do it the right way, follow the simple and very basic rules of Normalization.

Your schema at the moment violates the very first rule of normalization. At least get your database to comply with the first 3 normalization rules and it will make managing your application and your life much easier and simpler :) .

Comment: You are right, but this schema is already created.
The above answer is first splitting the comma separated values then checking it. We were using this and it was taking time to execute it as we have millions of records where we need to perform this action.

Comment: Seriously? You use comma separated data (millions of rows) in production, and search it with LIKE? You guys heard of NF? If you were storing this as `id int, userid int` with clustered index - it will be fast search. Just one question, WHY?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following way to resolve above issue.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.History 
WHERE (','+ RTRIM(ShareWith)+',') LIKE '%,'+CAST(@UserId AS VARCHAR)+',%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML to get a table from comma separated values:

```
DECLARE @x xml,
        @UserId int = 10

SELECT @x = (
    SELECT  id as '@id',
            CAST('<u>'+REPLACE(UserId,',','</u><u>') +'</u>' as xml)
    FROM YourTable
    FOR XML PATH('row')
)

SELECT  t.v.value('../@id','int') as id
FROM @x.nodes('/row/u') as t(v)
WHERE t.v.value('.','int') = @UserId
```

Output:

```
id
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you used your custom split function or standard STRING_SPLIT? In Azure Sql Database you can use STRING_SPLIT function to split strings:

```
SELECT mytable.*
FROM mytable
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(UserId , ',') ids
WHERE ids.value = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (if you are working in php)

```
$id = $checkId;
$sql= "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName like '%,". $id .",%' or ColumnName like 
      '". $id .",%' or ColumnName like '%,". $id ."' or ColumnName = ". $id;
```